# How to change File and Folder permissions on Windows 7 using Command Line (CLI)?

Tags: windows, file, command-line-interface, file-permissions, utility

I am trying to use chmod utility on windows command line but it does not work. I am looking for the command to change the files and folder permission on windows.

Comment: Just found the "icacls" command for windows. To find more information of the command just type "c:\icacls /?". The "icacls" command helps to change the file permission on windows.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following commands will help to take the ownership of the directory and files:
  D:\>takeown /f D:\path\to\directory /r /d y
  D:\>icacls D:\path\to\directory /grant administrators:F /t